# Meaning of PID, PPID and TGID

Tags: linux, process, linux-kernel, pid, threadgroup

What does the Linux kernel acronyms PID, PPID, TGID stand for?

I stumbled upon them at [strace-pids](https://github.com/serejkus/strace-pids#readme).

Answer (score 58, accepted):

- PID: Process Id
- PPID: Parent Process Id (the one which launched this PID)
- TGID: Thread Group Id

see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305992/linux-threads-and-process) for more details

Comment: This answer isn't always true -- specifically if reading the `event_data` field from linux/proc.sh. Confusingly, _pid refers to the `thread` id, and _tgid is the actual pid id. (see https://listman.redhat.com/archives/phil-list/2002-December/msg00020.html)