# why use thread in linux print same pid?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, pid

I am reading a book about unix .It said in linux , thread has different pid . And give the code below to print pid and thread id. I use SUSE and gcc.However, I get the same pid.Can anyone tell me why? Thanks.

```
#include "pthread.h"
pthread_t ntid;

void printids(const char *s)
{
    pid_t pid;
    pthread_t   tid;
    pid = getpid();
    tid = pthread_self();
    printf("%s pid = %u tid = %u  (0x%x)\n",s,(unsigned int)pid,(unsigned int)tid,(unsigned int)tid);
}
void *thr_fn(void *arg)
{
    printids("new thread :");
    return (void *)0;
}
int main()
{
    int err;
    err = pthread_create(&ntid,NULL,thr_fn,strerror(err));
    if(err != 0)
        err_quit("can't create new thread :%s\n",strerror(err));
    printids("main thread :");
    sleep(1);
    exit(0);
}
```

But,I get this:

```
main thread : pid = 2945 tid = 3075803392  (0xb7550900)
new thread : pid = 2945 tid = 3075799872  (0xb754fb40)
```

Comment: There must be an error in the book or you haven't read it properly.

Comment: You can find a nice explanation in the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305992/linux-threads-and-process

Comment: Thread implementations changed inside Linux (from X.Leroy's original threads to NPTL today), and the changes interacted with kernel changes.

Comment: @piokuc The book is Stevens《Advanced Programming in UNIX Environment》.   Is it old now?

Comment: Yes, it is an old book, but very good for the general Posix part. Linux specific parts could be less actual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Linux threads have the same thread when viewed from user space, from a view space they each have a separate PID.

See also: [Linux - Threads and Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305992/linux-threads-and-process)

Answer (score 0):

Threads are a concept in the same process, they always have the same pid. The pid only changes if you fork a process; in this case, the child process will have a different pid than the parent.

Comment: But the book said :linux use clone to create new thread .which means different pid.