# In the Linux kernel, what does it mean for a process to be "whole"?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, filestream

This code is from the file `/fs/proc/array.c` in the Linux headers. What does the `int whole` parameter mean? I want to know why sometimes you need to accumulate `min_flt` and `maj_flt`s from the `sig_struct` and other times it's ok to just read their values straight out of the `task_struct`

```
346 static int do_task_stat(struct seq_file *m, struct pid_namespace *ns,
347       struct pid *pid, struct task_struct *task, int whole)
...
406     /* add up live thread stats at the group level */
407     if (whole) {
408       struct task_struct *t = task;
409       do {
410         min_flt += t->min_flt;
411         maj_flt += t->maj_flt;
412         gtime = cputime_add(gtime, t->gtime);
413         t = next_thread(t);
414       } while (t != task);
415 
416       min_flt += sig->min_flt;
417       maj_flt += sig->maj_flt;
418       thread_group_times(task, &utime, &stime);
419       gtime = cputime_add(gtime, sig->gtime);
420     }
...
431   if (!whole) {
432     min_flt = task->min_flt;
433     maj_flt = task->maj_flt;
434     task_times(task, &utime, &stime);
435     gtime = task->gtime;
436   }
```

Answer (score 0):

"whole" is just an argument name and in this context it seems to indicate "`do_task_stat` for the whole thread group".

`do_task_stat` is a static function only used within `/fs/proc/array.c` It is used in two places: `proc_tid_stat` (TID is "thread ID") and `proc_tgid_stat` (TGID is "thread group ID").

See [Linux - Threads and Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305992/linux-threads-and-process) for good explaination of thread groups.