# android binder driver implementation

Tags: android, linux-device-driver, android-binder

I'm learning binder driver. It has a struct `binder_thread` for saving thread info. I find that it uses `binder_thread.pid` that is assigned with `current->pid` to distinguish each others. for example, in `binder_get_thread` method, that field is used to judge whether current thread has been add to the tree.

```
static struct binder_thread *binder_get_thread(struct binder_proc *proc)
{
    struct binder_thread *thread = NULL;
    struct rb_node *parent = NULL;
    struct rb_node **p = &proc->threads.rb_node;
    while (*p) {
        parent = *p;
        thread = rb_entry(parent, struct binder_thread, rb_node);
        if (current->pid < thread->pid)
            p = &(*p)->rb_left;
        else if (current->pid > thread->pid)
            p = &(*p)->rb_right;
        else
            break;
    }
    .....
}
```

But as I known, `current->pid` is the current process id, how can it be used for distinguishing threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit of confusing terminology, but at the kernel level each thread is assigned its own `pid` value which uniquely identifies it.  When a process is started, its first thread is given a unique `pid` and the thread group ID is set to be the same `pid`.  When new threads are created, they are given unique `pid` values but the same thread group ID so they have linkage back to their parent.  So this rb tree search code you are looking at will work because `current->pid` is the currently executing thread ID and it is comparing against the `thread->pid` values for the thread entries in the tree.

The answer from paxdiablo in this SO question explains the thread / process ID in some more detail, if you are interested:
[If threads share the same PID, how can they be identified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305992/if-threads-share-the-same-pid-how-can-they-be-identified)